# how to split data in 5 letters around one specific letter for each section

Tags: awk, sed

I have a data like this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

I am trying to find 5 letter left and 5 letters right to each F for each section and then calculate the number of E or D in each of them

a representative output looks like below

```
 >sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
    RQCSWFAGCTN   0  0
    LLYQLFRNLFC   0  0
    LFRNLFCSYGL   0  0
    NNSGLFFLCGN   0  0
    NSGLFFLCGNG   0  0
    GVYKGFPPKWS   0  0
    TNLRSFIHKVT   0  0
    >sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
    GQKITFHGEGD   1  1
    KDHAVFTRRGE   1  1
    RGEDLFMCMDI   1  2
    EALCGFQKPIS   1  0
    RLIIEFKVNFP   1  0
    EFKVNFPENGF   2  0
    FPENGFLSPDK   1  0
    >sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
    ATTPQFPDMIL   0  1
    RGHSHFVSDVV   0  1
    SSDGQFALSGS   0  1
    TTTRRFVGHTK   0  0
    VLSVAFSSDNR   0  1
    VSCVRFSPNSS   0  0
    >sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
    VLIKLFCVHTK   0  0 
    DVQIRFQPQL    0  1
    >sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
    LLLLAFLLLPR   0  0
    KRCGGFLIRDD   0  2
    LIRDDFVLTAA   0  2
    EPTQQFIPVKR   1  0
    YNPKNFSNDIM   0  1
    >sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
    GAEEKFKEIAE   4  0
    RKREIFDRYGE   2  1
    ANGTSFSYTFH   0  0
    SFSYTFHGDPH   0  1
    DPHAMFAEFFG   0  1
    AMFAEFFGGRN   1  0
    MFAEFFGGRNP   1  0
    GGRNPFDTFFG   0  1
    NPFDTFFGQRN   0  1
    PFDTFFGQRNG   0  1
    DIDDPFSGFPM   0  3
    DPFSGFPMGMG   0  1 
    MGMGGFTNVNF   0  0 
    FTNVNFGRSRS   0  0
    >sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
    DGYVKFWQIYI   0  1   
    LSCLLFCDNHK   0  1
    DPDVPFWRFLI   0  2
    VPFWRFLITGA   0  0
    LQTIRFSPDIF   0  1
    FSPDIFSSVSV   0  1
    EGHACFSSISE   0  0
    SSISEFLLTHP   1  0
    HPVLSFGIQVV   0  0
    VLIKLFCVHTK   0  0
    DVQIRFQPQLN   0  1
    TAHEDFTFGES   2  1
    HEDFTFGESRP   2  1
    PAPADFLSLSS   0  1
    MTPDAFMTPSA   0  1
    >sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
    ISLGIFPLPAG   0  0
    SEQWKFQELSQ   2  0
    EENEGFVKVTD   3  1
    IENKAFDRNTE   2  1
    NTESLFEELSS   3  0
    AQRKRFTRVEM   1  0
    SSIWQFFSRLF   0  0
    SIWQFFSRLFS   0  0
    FFSRLFSSSSN   0  0
```

at the begging I thought of finding the 5 letters left and right to F.
but I could not figure it out how to do that

Comment: You REALLY accept those answers fast! For your next question you might want to give it a few hours before accepting an answer as the first one you get MAY be the best possible answer or it may not and you'll never know if you discourage people from posting answers by accepting an early answer quickly.

Comment: @Ed Morton I know but I see that some spending so much time to help me, even if their answer might not work, I still learn a lottttttt . That is fantastic and I value the time of others. However you are right, I get excited so quickly :-D

Comment: I understand the sentiment but no-ones expecting you to accept an answer quickly and you're kinda shooting yourself in the foot if you do as you'll miss seeing a lot of good answers.

Comment: @Ed Morton ok, I will try for the next question and see :-) thanks for all your guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this Perl solution

```
 perl -lne ' if (/^[^>]/) { while(/(?<=(\w{5}))F(?=(\w{5}))/g) { $x="$1F$2";$e=()=$x=~/E/g; $d=()=$x=~/D/g; print "$x $e $d" } } else { print }'  5letter.txt
```

**EDIT1:**

`DVQIRFQPQL 0 1  # Edge case`

For accommodating the edge case as mentioned by OP in the comments - the string to the right of F can be less than 5 letters if it is at the end of the line

```
 perl -lne ' if (/^[^>]/) { while(/(?<=(.{5}))F(?=(.{0,5}))/g) { $x="$1F$2";$e=()=$x=~/E/g; $d=()=$x=~/D/g; print "$x $e $d" } } else { print }' 5letter.txt
```

For each line that doesn't start with `>`, use positive lookbehind to match 5 letter \w to the left of F and positive lookahead to match 5 letter \w to the right of F. Using while loop and /g on the match operator scan the line and for each match copy the $1F$2 into variable $x. Use list context and count the occurrences of E and D. Print the result finally.

with given inputs

```
$ perl -lne ' if (/^[^>]/) { while(/(?<=(.{5}))F(?=(.{0,5}))/g) { $x="$1F$2";$e=()=$x=~/E/g; $d=()=$x=~/D/g; print "$x $e $d" } } else { print }' 5letter.txt
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RQCSWFAGCTN 0 0
LLYQLFRNLFC 0 0
LFRNLFCSYGL 0 0
NNSGLFFLCGN 0 0
NSGLFFLCGNG 0 0
GVYKGFPPKWS 0 0
TNLRSFIHKVT 0 0
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
GQKITFHGEGD 1 1
KDHAVFTRRGE 1 1
RGEDLFMCMDI 1 2
EALCGFQKPIS 1 0
RLIIEFKVNFP 1 0
EFKVNFPENGF 2 0
FPENGFLSPDK 1 1
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
ATTPQFPDMIL 0 1
RGHSHFVSDVV 0 1
SSDGQFALSGS 0 1
TTTRRFVGHTK 0 0
VLSVAFSSDNR 0 1
VSCVRFSPNSS 0 0
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
VLIKLFCVHTK 0 0
DVQIRFQPQL 0 1
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
LLLLAFLLLPR 0 0
KRCGGFLIRDD 0 2
LIRDDFVLTAA 0 2
EPTQQFIPVKR 1 0
YNPKNFSNDIM 0 1
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
GAEEKFKEIAE 4 0
RKREIFDRYGE 2 1
ANGTSFSYTFH 0 0
SFSYTFHGDPH 0 1
DPHAMFAEFFG 1 1
AMFAEFFGGRN 1 0
MFAEFFGGRNP 1 0
GGRNPFDTFFG 0 1
NPFDTFFGQRN 0 1
PFDTFFGQRNG 0 1
DIDDPFSGFPM 0 3
DPFSGFPMGMG 0 1
MGMGGFTNVNF 0 0
FTNVNFGRSRS 0 0
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
DGYVKFWQIYI 0 1
LSCLLFCDNHK 0 1
DPDVPFWRFLI 0 2
VPFWRFLITGA 0 0
LQTIRFSPDIF 0 1
FSPDIFSSVSV 0 1
EGHACFSSISE 2 0
SSISEFLLTHP 1 0
HPVLSFGIQVV 0 0
VLIKLFCVHTK 0 0
DVQIRFQPQLN 0 1
TAHEDFTFGES 2 1
HEDFTFGESRP 2 1
PAPADFLSLSS 0 1
MTPDAFMTPSA 0 1
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
ISLGIFPLPAG 0 0
SEQWKFQELSQ 2 0
EENEGFVKVTD 3 1
IENKAFDRNTE 2 1
NTESLFEELSS 3 0
AQRKRFTRVEM 1 0
SSIWQFFSRLF 0 0
SIWQFFSRLFS 0 0
FFSRLFSSSSN 0 0

$
```

**PS:**

```
$ echo "RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLT
 RYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR" | perl -ne ' if (/^[^>]/) { $y=$_;while(/(.{10})/g) { $x=$1; $c++ for($x=~/F/g) ; print "$x $c\n"; $c=0 } } '
RNDDDDTSVC
LGTRQCSWFA 1
GCTNRTWNSS 0
AVPLIGLPNT 0
QDYKWVDRNS 0
GLTWSGNDTC 0
LYSCQNQTKG 0
LLYQLFRNLF 2
CSYGLTEAHG 0
KWRCADASIT 0
NDKGHDGHRT 0
PTWWLTGSNL 0
TLSVNNSGLF 1
FLCGNGVYKG 1
FPPKWSGRCG 1
LGYLVPSLT  0
RYLTLNASQI 0
TNLRSFIHKV 1

$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188309/discussion-on-answer-by-stack0114106-how-to-split-data-in-5-letters-around-one-s).

Comment: You can simplify `(?=(.{5}|.+?$))` to `(?=(.{0,5}))` that will (greedily) take **up to** 5 characters.

Answer (score 5):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR%2 {print; next }                                # print every odd record
{                                                  # the even records are processed
    while(match($0,/.{5}F.{0,5}/)) {               # get 5 before and upto 5 after F
        # 5 before F ^^^   ^^^ 0-5 chars after F 
        # change to /.{0,5}F.{0,5}/ if needed
        print s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),         # print match
              gsub(/E/,"E",s),                     # count of Es
              gsub(/D/,"D",s)                      # count of Ds
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+1)                     # shorten the search string
    }
}' file
```

Some output:

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RQCSWFAGCTN 0 0
LLYQLFRNLFC 0 0    # notice another F in the 5+F+5 window
LFRNLFCSYGL 0 0    # .. getting handled
NNSGLFFLCGN 0 0
NSGLFFLCGNG 0 0
GVYKGFPPKWS 0 0
TNLRSFIHKVT 0 0
...
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
VLIKLFCVHTK 0 0
DVQIRFQPQL 0 1     # ...F{0,5}
```

Comment: superb! Nitpick: you're converting D's to E's but since the string is not used anymore, just replace with "".

Comment: @James Brown it discarding some that does not have 5 letter aside, like `>sp|P04637|` and also it discarded some in `>sp|P13674|`, do you know what is going on?

Comment: Hmm, now that I think of it, it probably skips the Fs that are in the previous 5. Let me fix that.

Comment: @JamesBrown.. the question needs update.. just check my EDIT1 for the edge case to be covered.

Comment: @stack0114106 Nice catch. So, the last char in the string can be F but not the first?

Comment: ideally, yes.. but OP has mentioned that it can be less than 5

Comment: This really broke my concentration in TF2. :D

Comment: TF2??..not getting you..:-)

Comment: Team Fortress 2 :D

Comment: Now I'm bothered by those blue words in my output.

Comment: Nice answer, you fixed the problem with `F` having less then 5 characters in the end, but to complete, you miss the one with F somewhere in the first 5 characters.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused about the reqs at this point, might be this TF2 I'm playing.

Comment: Correction, you will miss the first 4 characters in a string like `XXXXXFXFXXXX` since, for the second `F` you will only look at `XFXXXXXX` and not at `XXXFXFXXXXX`

Comment: True, but as there was no such case in the sample data I'm not really sure about it so I just commented it in the code. The reqs never change in the real life, right? Right?!

Answer (score 2):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^>/ { print; next }
{
    fpos = 0
    while ( match(substr($0,fpos+1),/F/) ) {
        fpos += RSTART
        str  = substr($0,fpos-5,11)
        print str, gsub(/E/,"&",str), gsub(/D/,"&",str)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RQCSWFAGCTN 0 0
LLYQLFRNLFC 0 0
LFRNLFCSYGL 0 0
NNSGLFFLCGN 0 0
NSGLFFLCGNG 0 0
GVYKGFPPKWS 0 0
TNLRSFIHKVT 0 0
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
GQKITFHGEGD 1 1
KDHAVFTRRGE 1 1
RGEDLFMCMDI 1 2
EALCGFQKPIS 1 0
RLIIEFKVNFP 1 0
EFKVNFPENGF 2 0
FPENGFLSPDK 1 1
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
ATTPQFPDMIL 0 1
RGHSHFVSDVV 0 1
SSDGQFALSGS 0 1
TTTRRFVGHTK 0 0
VLSVAFSSDNR 0 1
VSCVRFSPNSS 0 0
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
VLIKLFCVHTK 0 0
DVQIRFQPQL 0 1
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
LLLLAFLLLPR 0 0
KRCGGFLIRDD 0 2
LIRDDFVLTAA 0 2
EPTQQFIPVKR 1 0
YNPKNFSNDIM 0 1
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
GAEEKFKEIAE 4 0
RKREIFDRYGE 2 1
ANGTSFSYTFH 0 0
SFSYTFHGDPH 0 1
DPHAMFAEFFG 1 1
AMFAEFFGGRN 1 0
MFAEFFGGRNP 1 0
GGRNPFDTFFG 0 1
NPFDTFFGQRN 0 1
PFDTFFGQRNG 0 1
DIDDPFSGFPM 0 3
DPFSGFPMGMG 0 1
MGMGGFTNVNF 0 0
FTNVNFGRSRS 0 0
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
DGYVKFWQIYI 0 1
LSCLLFCDNHK 0 1
DPDVPFWRFLI 0 2
VPFWRFLITGA 0 0
LQTIRFSPDIF 0 1
FSPDIFSSVSV 0 1
EGHACFSSISE 2 0
SSISEFLLTHP 1 0
HPVLSFGIQVV 0 0
VLIKLFCVHTK 0 0
DVQIRFQPQLN 0 1
TAHEDFTFGES 2 1
HEDFTFGESRP 2 1
PAPADFLSLSS 0 1
MTPDAFMTPSA 0 1
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
ISLGIFPLPAG 0 0
SEQWKFQELSQ 2 0
EENEGFVKVTD 3 1
IENKAFDRNTE 2 1
NTESLFEELSS 3 0
AQRKRFTRVEM 1 0
SSIWQFFSRLF 0 0
SIWQFFSRLFS 0 0
FFSRLFSSSSN 0 0
```

Comment: you are great at awk , wow, I just can tell you wow , I liked it already

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of the excellent solution of [James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657379/8344060). The adaptation makes it POSIX compliant, and also corrects for the single case where two `F` values are less than 5 characters apart. Example:

```
 ...RQCSWFAGFCTNRQS...
         ^  ^
```

The first window should detect `RQCSWFAGFCT` while the second window should detect `SWFAGFCTNRQ`. In the proposed solution, it will only detect `AGFCTNRQ`, or it might not detect the second `F` at all. (depending on the usage of `.{0,5}F.{0,5}` or `.{5}F.{0,5}` as a regex.

```
awk '
NR%2 {print; next }                                # print every odd record
{                                                  # the even records are processed
    seq=$0; l=lseq=length($0)
    while(match(seq,/F/)) {                        # find `F`
        n = l - lseq + RSTART                      # get position in $0
        print s=substr($0,n-5,(n<6?n+5:11)),       # print match and 
                                                   # correct if F is in the first 5
              gsub(/E/,"E",s),                     # count of Es
              gsub(/D/,"D",s)                      # count of Ds
        seq=substr(seq,RSTART+1)                   # shorten the search string
        lseq=lseq-RSTART
    }
}' file.fasta
```

You might be also interested in [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk), it is an adapted version of awk which is tuned to process FASTA files.

This gives the result:

```
bioawk -c fastx '{ print ">" $name }
                 { tmp=$seq; l=ltmp=length($seq)
                   while(match(tmp,/F/)) {
                      n=l-ltmp+RSTART
                      print s=substr($seq,n,(n<6?n+5:11)),
                            gsub(/E/,"E",s),
                            gsub(/D/,"D",s)
                      tmp=substr(tmp,RSTART+1)
                      ltmp=ltmp-RSTART
                   }}' file.fasta
```

Here `$name` is the sequence name (everything after `>`), and `$seq` is the complete sequence, even if you have a sequence spanning multiple lines.

---

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Comment: should I install this script? how is that supported ?

Comment: @Learner If you do not have bioawk, you have to download and install it from the site I linked.

Comment: so the solution above won't work? what is in the bioawk that can distinguished those FF that are next to each other while awk cannot ?

Comment: @Learner The first solution will work with any normal version of awk (gawk, mawk, posix awk, ...). The second solution will only work if you have the program bioawk installed. Both solutions will produce exactly the same result. The main difference between bioawk and normal awk is that it can read fasta-files without any hocus-spocus. In normal awk, the record is defined as a single line (by default), in bioawk, a record is the full sequence (name + sequence)

Comment: sorry for lots of questions , I am more interested in awk , so your solution will be more precise than that of awk above, right? I already liked your answer anyway

Comment: @Learner The above solution will solve a potential case which was not available in both the perl and awk solutions before. Since we did not have data which encountered such a case, the problem was not addressed.

Comment: but I have some sections that F is next to another F, right? sorry I am confused :-)

Comment: @kvantour.. no my solution works for the case ````XXXXXFXFXXXX```` that you mentioned..

Comment: @kvantour.. the perl solution uses lookahead and lookbehind features which doesn't consumer words/characters.. so it moves character by character and covers the case that you mentioned ````echo "XXXXXFXFXXXX" | perl -lne ' if (/^[^>]/) { while(/(?<=(.{5}))F(?=(.{5}|.+?$))/g) { $x="$1F$2";$e=()=$x=~/E/g; $d=()=$x=~/D/g; print "$x $e $d" } } else { print
 }'
XXXXXFXFXXX 0 0
XXXFXFXXXX 0 0````

Comment: @kvantour.. np.. there is also bioperl https://bioperl.org/ for working with FASTA files..